# What prop-type should I use for a material-ui icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-proptypes, google-material-icons

I have a component that allows you to pass an icon in as a prop, with a default

```
import DefaultIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FeedbackOutlined';
const MyIconWrapper = ({Icon}) = (<Icon/>)
```

And the prop-type of:

```
MyIconWrapper.propTypes = { Icon: PropTypes.element }
MyIconWrapper.defaultProps = { Icon: DefaultIcon }
```

Because the icon is a component (looking at the source code it seems to be)?

However I get a prop-type warning about not being an element. It's in fact an object.

I have currently got this as my prop-type

```
MyIconWrapper.propTypes = { 
    Icon: PropTypes.shape({
        displayName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        type: PropTypes.shape({ render: PropTypes.func.isRequired })
    }) 
};
```

But this seems like I'm just redefining a react element?

Is this the correct prop-type for an icon or is there a better one to use?

Comment: in my openion, it should be just react element, "PropTypes.element"

Comment: @Roy.B, it's not a matter of *opinion*, as the prop-type library does not recognize them as elements: "**However I get a prop-type warning about not being an element. It's in fact an object.**"

Comment: that's because of the way you export the icon

Comment: @Roy.B do you mean Import? What about that is problematic?

Comment: Can the new `elementType` help with that? https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/pull/211

Comment: @chrispop yes that's perfect. And I've found a duplicate question candidate as well.